# Get words of a sentence into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, sentence

How does one go about having a user input a sentence, and the program picking the words apart and putting each word into a vector.
I've tried something like this, but it ends up stalling:

```
vector<string> sentence;
string nextWord = "notyetdefined";

cout << "Type your sentence:" << endl;
while (nextWord != "" && nextWord != "\n") {
    cin >> nextWord;
    sentence.push_back(nextWord);
}
```

I've also tried detecting for a period at the end of the sentence which works, but is annoying that the user would have to put a period everytime, because they might often forget, resulting in an endless loop that I'm not sure how to deal with.

EDIT: Managed to find a fix by using this question: [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) that was suggested to me in the comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Comment: @Pradhan, I'm surprised it even compiles at all

Comment: When do you want it to end? If the user types **Roses are red. Violets\n are blue** then what result do you want?

Comment: 'twas a mistype guys, i didn't copy-paste this, so human error is possible.

Comment: Maybe instead use getline(cin, ...) and then split the line into tokens?

Comment: @Beta Whenever they press enter, or whenever there is a newline. In your sentence, right after Violets.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27125803/3807729

Comment: Then I'd use `getline` and `stringstream`.